# Deploy MVC4 application in IIS of Windows server 2003

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2003

Trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC4 mobile application to IIS6 on Windows Server 2003, but it is showing access denied permission error in the browser.

Comment: We need LOTS more information. What have you done? what's in the root folder? have you 'bin' deployed? etc

Comment: root folder contain ActionFilter,global.ascx, controller, model,view, config

Comment: You might as well have posted the question 'Need to learn the entire history of physics by 7:30pm tonight'.

Comment: Not at all.How could you ask such things.if you knew the answer you could have answer it.